# Can the property be null ever or is VS wrong?

Tags: c#, null, null-coalescing-operator

Having the following class, I protected it against null for `Values`.

```
public class Container
{
  public Guid Id { get; init; }
  public virtual IEnumerable<Measure> Measures { get; init; }
  public Dictionary<string, Measure[]> Measurement 
    => (Measures ?? Array.Empty<Measure>())
      .GroupBy(a => a.Type).ToDictionary(a => a.Key, a => a.ToArray());
}

public class Measure
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

For some reason, my IDE marks the coalescing as superfluous, claiming that the property will never be null (i.e. `Measures??Array.Empty<Measure>()` may be refactored to `Measures`).

```
public class Container
{
  public Guid Id { get; init; }
  public virtual IEnumerable<Measure> Measures { get; init; }
  public Dictionary<string, Measure[]> Measurement 
    => Measures
      .GroupBy(a => a.Type).ToDictionary(a => a.Key, a => a.ToArray());
}
```

When I followed that advice, a colleague pointed out that it's flawed. I **agree with him** but *it's a bug in VS/R#* is rearly a realistic explanation. More realistic is: *it's us being wrong*. So I sense that we're both missing something and that the IDE is right, somehow.

[image]

I can't explain how, though.

What I tried was to removing `virtual`, adding `= default!` and a few other alterations. Regardless, excuting in [this in a fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3chW7r), throws `ArgumentNullException` if the coalescing is removed.

Comment: Don't use `init`. Use a proper constructor. `init` has surprisingly few legitimate use cases.

Comment: And never use `= default!` or `= null!` either (I know the EF example code uses it for `DbSet` members, but outside of that situation there is never a good reason to do that, and even then I feel the EF examples are _wrong_ but give people the stupid-quick-fix to keep the samples shorter).

Comment: But dotnetfiddle doesn't mark the coalescing as superfluous, neither visual studio. Perhaps your IDE thinks `IEnumerable<Measure>` will never be null, but `IEnumerable<Measure>?` will.

Comment: @shingo It could be VS or R# (i.e. Resharper). Both are reliable and likely "smarter" than me, in my opinion. Usually. Please see the edit. As for the `IEnumerable<T>?` - I thought that is nullable by default and the explicit nullability mark would be unnecessary.

Comment: @Dai Interesting suggestion. How exactly would the recommended syntax be, then? EF requires an empty constructor (in which I could assign to the virtual properties). But then, EF sets the values using the initializer, so I can't use `{get;}` only. Hence, I'd land into `{get;set;}` making the values mutable. Isn't that frown upon or at least discouraged?

Comment: Are you saying `Measure` is an EF entity type? (and [EFCore 7 now (finally) supports using ctors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors), btw)

Comment: You have other design-issues: your `Container.Measurement` property should not return a new mutable `Dictionary` for every invocation, as that's expensive and wasteful (and violates the contract that property-getters are _computationally-cheap_). Instead change it to a method, or change it to return an `ILookup<String,Measure>` _view_ of your `Measures` member (via `ToLookup()` in Linq).

Comment: @Dai Yes, the measures are stored in the database and loaded in as a long, compounded list of data. During the usage, those are chunked up by group (which happens only once and only for a single type, not known which in advance, though).

Comment: @KonradViltersten (Why are you storing data in a denormalized fashion?) - so your `Measurement` type is not actually mapped to a table by EF? (i.e. you don't have a `DbSet<Measurement>` in your `DbContext`? In that case then what I said doesn't apply, because EF won't be the one instantiating `Measurement` so there's no need to compromise your classes' design to satisfy EF's need for a default ctor or mutable properties).

Comment: @Dai I see why it's surprising. It's due to the requirement: we store **a set** of *measures*, while we're using **a subset** of them, hence partitioned as *measurement*, where each key denotes the type of the subset. Sorry for not being sufficiently clear from the start. Now, that said, are you suggesting that I change the design of the classes and, more importantly, is the coalescing actually superfluous?

Comment: That should be resharper because I don't have it installed. Since nullable reference types have been introduced, a reference type without the question mark should be considered non-null. The prompt in the screenshot also explains this: _"according to nullable reference types' annotations"_. You may disable nullable check on the project if you prefer the previous style.

Comment: @shingo Would you post that as an answer to be accepted, please? Without questioning your statement, I wonder if you have a reference to the claim that reference types are supposed to be considered non-null unless explicitly stated as such. It makes a lot of sense to me.

Comment: It's not a bug in VS or ReSharper - it's a "bug" in the design of the C# language: your `Measures` property returns `null` **in violation** of the not-`null` contract on the property (because there's no `?` modifier), but the C# language _trusts_ you to ensure that `init` properties are set in an object-initializer - if there's no object-initializer used with `new Container` then the property will remain `null`, but C# won't give you a warning about that (unless you use C# 10 and add the `required` modifier to the property).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The NRT document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) mentions:

> Any variable where the `?` isn't appended to the type name is a **non-nullable reference type**. That includes all reference type variables in existing code when you've enabled this feature.

Therefore, if nullable is enabled on the project, based on this standard the analyzer should assume that `Measures` will never be null.

FYI, if you have not initialized the `Measures` property, you should see a CS8618 warning, though you can ignore it. If you want to avoid ignoring this warning, you can add "nullable" to the "Treat specific warnings as error" in the project settings to report compilation errors.

Comment: Unfortunately the compiler makes this assumption despite the property never ever actually being set anywhere due to use of `init`.

Comment: It should not due to use of `init`. I tested it and even if I use `set` or use `get` only, VS will still tell me _"'Measures' is not null here"_.

Comment: That's not what I meant - I meant that C# won't warn that `class Container`'s `Measures` property is not guaranteed to always be set (i.e. that it _will_ be `null` if the `init` property is never set at the point of construction).

Comment: @Dai I get the sensation that this nullability concept is, maybe not broken, but kind-of-poorly supported at the moment. Like they wanted to make and and got half-way through. Then, release window came an a PL told them to go with it. Or am I missing a bigger picture here?

Comment: @KonradViltersten Back when they introduced it in .NET Core 3.1 around 2019, yes - but since then (and since C# 10.0) the "workaround" for non-nullable `init` properties actually-being-`null`-due-to-never-being-set is to add the `required` modifier (or just use a constructor...).

Answer (score -1):

It looks like very related to 'Nullable' project setting:
[image]

**UPD** I was not able to reproduce IDE's message regardless of 'Nullable' setting.

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.6.0

With 'Nullbale' is 'Enable':

1>------ Build started: Project: WinFormsApp3, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------

1>C:\Users\TMSAdmin\source\WinFormsApp3\WinFormsApp3\Form1.cs(99,23,99,27): warning CS8618: Non-nullable property 'Name' must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring the property as nullable.

1>C:\Users\TMSAdmin\source\WinFormsApp3\WinFormsApp3\Form1.cs(100,23,100,27): warning CS8618: Non-nullable property 'Type' must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring the property as nullable.

1>C:\Users\TMSAdmin\source\WinFormsApp3\WinFormsApp3\Form1.cs(92,45,92,53): warning CS8618: Non-nullable property 'Measures' must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring the property as nullable.

1>WinFormsApp3 -> C:\Users\TMSAdmin\source\WinFormsApp3\WinFormsApp3\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows\WinFormsApp3.dll

1>Done building project "WinFormsApp3.csproj".

========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: It might be easier of you show the resulting lines in CSPROJ instead. The GUI of the settings may differ between IDEs. As for the message, it **might** be provided by R# not VS itself. Both are quite reliable, though, so I trust there's something to it. Unless confirmed otherwise, hence my question. (NB. Not my down-vote.)